# Not Getting refresh token while using Gmail API in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

We are using the google_sign_in package for Gmail API. Our motive is to read the emails of users but when users allow access we are unable to get a refresh token to read the mails of users. We required access token as well as refresh token so that we can access the mail for a longer time.

we are developing this in flutter, any leads regarding this will be helpful

Comment: Please include your code to get the token so that it will be more descriptive

Comment: final _googleSignIn = new GoogleSignIn(
        scopes: [
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly',
        ],
      );  in this i get only acesses token and id token and not refresh token

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.